# Prove that the set of equalizers is a sub $F$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, ring-homomorphism

Let $A$ and $B$ be $F$-algebras, and let $φ_i : A → B$ be an $F$-algebra homomorphism, for $i$ ranging over some index set $I$. Deﬁne the equalizer $E$ to be the set of $a ∈ A$ such that for all $i,j ∈ I$, we have $φ_i(a) = φ_j(a)$.

I need to prove that E is a sub-$F$-algebra of $A$.

I am wondering what we need to check to show that $E$ is a sub-$F$- algebra. The $R$-algebra $A$ is defined as an ordered pair $(A,i)$ where $i: R\rightarrow A$ is a ring homomorphism. But we have not been given that what is a sub-$F$-algebra.

I guess this question is asking us to prove that regard $F$ algebra $A$ as a $F$ vector space, we need to prove that $E$ is a subspace.

So I am thinking about this:

check of closure under addition:

if $a,b\in E$, $\phi_i(a+b)=\phi_i(a)+\phi_j(b)=\phi_j(a)+\phi_j(b)=\phi_j(a+b)$.

check of closure under scaler multiplication:

if $a\in E,m\in F$, 
$\phi_i(ma)=\phi_i(m)\phi_i(a)=m\phi_i(a)=m\phi_j(a)=\phi_j(m)\phi_j(a)=\phi_j(ma)$.

check of $0$ and $1$:
$\phi_i(0)=0=\phi_j(0),\phi_i(1)=1=\phi_j(1)$

So am I correct? Could someone please check if I get it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems correct. Closure under multiplication. 0 and 1 should be in the subalgebra.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Got it. Thanks for veriffication!